# Tensorflow estimator: Switching to careful_interpolation to get the correct PR-AUC of a model

Tags: python, tensorflow

In my project, I am using the premade estimator `DNNClassifier`.
Here is my estimator:

```
model = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
        hidden_units=network,
        feature_columns=feature_cols,
        n_classes= 2,
        activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
        optimizer=tf.train.ProximalAdagradOptimizer(
            learning_rate=0.1,
            l1_regularization_strength=0.001
        ),
        config=chk_point_run_config,
        model_dir=MODEL_CHECKPOINT_DIR
    )
```

when I evaluate the model using `eval_res = model.evaluate(..)`,
I get the following warning:

> WARNING:tensorflow:Trapezoidal rule is known to produce incorrect PR-AUCs; please switch to "careful_interpolation" instead.

How I can switch to careful_interpolation to get the correct results from the `evaluate()` method?

Tensorflow version: `1.8`

Comment: When you create the PR-AUC metric you need to specify the summation method. If you show us how you construct your estimator I can point you to what needs to chang

Comment: @Alexandre Passos Thanks.. I have added the estimator for you..

Comment: It looks like you might need to file a github issue since this metric is added by estimator and not by you.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, the use of a pre-made estimator leaves little freedom for customizing the evaluation process. Currently, a `DNNClassifier` does not seem to provide a means to adjust the evaluation metrics, likewise for other estimators.

Albeit not ideal, one solution is to augment an estimator with the desired metrics using [`tf.contrib.metrics.add_metrics`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/estimator/add_metrics), which will replace the old metric if the exact same key is assigned to the new one:

> If there is a name conflict between this and estimators existing metrics, this will override the existing one.

It comes with the advantage of working for any estimator that produces probabilistic predictions, at the expense of still calculating the overridden metric for each evaluation. A `DNNClassifier` estimator provides logistic values (between 0 and 1) under the key `'logistic'` (the list of possible keys in canned estimators are [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.9/tensorflow/python/estimator/canned/prediction_keys.py)). This might not always be the case for other estimator heads, but alternatives may be available: in a multi-label classifier built with [`tf.contrib.estimator.multi_label_head`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/estimator/multi_label_head), `logistic` is not available, but `probabilities` can be used instead.

Hence, the code would look like this:

```
def metric_auc(labels, predictions):
    return {
        'auc_precision_recall': tf.metrics.auc(
            labels=labels, predictions=predictions['logistic'], num_thresholds=200,
            curve='PR', summation_method='careful_interpolation')
    }

estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(...)
estimator = tf.contrib.estimator.add_metrics(estimator, metric_auc)
```

When evaluating, the warning message will still appear, but the AUC with careful interpolation will be called shortly afterwards. Assigning this metric to a different key would also allow you to check the discrepancy between the two summation methods. My tests on a multi-label logistic regression task show that the measurements may indeed be slightly different: auc_precision_recall = 0.05173396, auc_precision_recall_careful = 0.05059402.

---

There is also a reason why the default summation method is still `'trapezoidal'`, in spite of the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/auc) suggesting that careful interpolation is "strictly preferred". As [commented in pull request #19079](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/19079#issuecomment-394492310), the change would be significantly backwards incompatible. Subsequent comments on the same pull request suggest the workaround above.

Comment: How come using a DNNClassifier we should use logistic as prediction key? As I thought, prediction key should be probabilities for classifiers.

Comment: @ElonaMishmika This is just how the estimator is implemented. Not all pre-made estimators use `probabilities` as key to the classifier's output.

Comment: Okay. Actually I ask this is because I'm trying to use LinearClassifier, and when I check their github [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/estimator/canned/head.py), in line 1185, they seem to have defined all different prediction keys. I don't know which one to use / the difference between logistic and probabilities.